# 147GB vs. 146GB HP Drives

Tags: hard-drive, hp, performance, hp-smart-array

I'm kind of scratching my head here.

One of our clients has a DL180 with 4 x 146GB SAS drives, they show up in ACU as 147GB drives. We ordered spares from HP, and they show as 146GB in ACU and therefore it will not rebuild! I'm a little confused.

I've never seen a 147GB sas drive. Checking some compatibility lists against the part numbers we do see that the different the disks are supposed to be compatible or interchangeable.

Has anyone had to deal with this?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a HP geek, let me have the full server part number and the part numbers of both types of disks and I'll do some digging for you.

Comment: The existing drives all had the following information: 146.8GB 15000RPM, MODEL DF146A9845, PART# 392254-003, there is an HP sticker below that says D96KTP8, FIRMWARE HPD0

Comment: I need to know the specific generation of DL180 - do you have a part number?

Comment: The attempted replacement drive from HP shows: 146GB 15K SAS, MODEL DF0146B8052, PN: 454228-001, HP sticker shows 325Y2N0

Comment: I'll have to go look for that.

Comment: it's probably a 442853-xx or a 442854-xx (i.e. a G4)

Comment: actually Tom I've got to the bottom of it, basically HP buy disks from all the various sources and while they're all very similar there are some differences. What's happened is that the original disks are VERY slightly bigger than the replacements that have been bought - they'll never be able to replace the existing one - they'll have to either backup the array, rebuild it from scratch with the new disks and restore or source some more of the original disks. Sorry to bum you out :(

Comment: Thanks for you help! I kind of figured this would be the case. What sucks is they are LARGER so disk imaging might be a bit of an issue.

Comment: I advised them to just go bigger! I don't know why I didn't think of that earlier I was so hung up on the 146 vs 147 gb issue. A 300GB drive should smartsize down right?

Comment: It definitely will do - bit of a waste but it will yes.